# Steam crashes with no error message after updating to 20.04

Tags: games, steam, 20.04

Since upgrading to 20.04 from 19.10, Steam does not launch. I have tried installing via `steam`, `steam-installer` and the `steam.deb` on their website. None of these work. Between each I have deleted `~/Steam`, `~/.local/share/Steam` and `~/.steam` and purged.

When Steam crashes, though, it gives no error. It just stops.

Output of `steam`

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/USER/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2020-05-13 16:35:13] Startup - updater built Apr 27 2020 21:53:21
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-05-13 16:35:13] Checking for update on startup
[2020-05-13 16:35:13] Checking for available updates...
[2020-05-13 16:35:13] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-05-13 16:35:14] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1588032389, installed version 1588032389
[2020-05-13 16:35:14] Nothing to do
[2020-05-13 16:35:14] Verifying installation...
[2020-05-13 16:35:14] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-05-13 16:35:15] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

Output of `strace steam` at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/LzyYwtE5)

Comment: Hi, it's unclear to me if you have tried simply installing from the repos with `sudo apt install steam`? Or did you download installer from a website and that did not work? Because in my own case I do not see the line with "debian-installation", it says ubuntu instead

Comment: @kurja In this case, `sudo apt install steam-installer`, but I've tried that, the `steam` package and the `steam.deb` on Steam's website

Comment: `sudo apt install steam` is what worked for me; please try that.

Comment: @kurja I've already tried that.

Comment: from what I recall steam-installer is just an installer for steam (I don't even have that installed now, just `steam`); if that's what you have now, can you run steam-installer, does that do anything?

Comment: @kurja ```steam-installer
  Depends: <steam> (= 1:1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3)
    steam:i386
``` It works by depending on steam and the necessary libraries. `steam-installer` is not a command, however `steam` is.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in KDE neon, after it updated to ubuntu 20.04. I still didint find a solution that works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by purging `steam:i386`, removing the `~/.steam` folder and then reinstalling.

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge steam:i386`

`mv ~/.steam ~/.steam.old`

`sudo apt install steam`

Note that `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge steam*` did not remove it for some reason.
I see that OP did the that, I'm not sure whether `i386` was specified explicitly.